# when boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp file is included

Tags: boost

How can I find when (which version) above file, **boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp**, is included in **Boost**?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the individual libraries do not have a standalone version. One should use the associated boost version instead.

The [BOOST_VERSION](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html) macro can be checked at compile time to determine the version of boost, and by association the version of the Property Tree library.